# How do I make sure I get all the digits past the decimal out of Excel and into MySQL

Tags: java, excel, jdbc

I inherited a Java app that uses POI to read data from an Excel file into a MySQL DB. I'm noticing that cells that have numbers like 12.345678 are being read in as 12.3457 but I can't afford in this application to have the number rounded.

After some investigation it appears that my problem is not with POI. I saw that the value was read with POI correctly, placed into the insert statement correctly, but when executed, the DB did not contain the full precision.

Comment: Which version of POI are you using? cell.getNumericCellValue() works fine with version 3.8-beta5 and reading XLSX file format.

Comment: You do know that the Excel .xls file format stores numbers as IEEE floats, don't you? They don't get stored with a specific number of digits, that's just formatting applied on the display side...

Comment: I am using 3.7. I'll have to try digging into the application source to see if I find anything obvious (like calling the wrong method on cell, etc.) I'm curious if having the column in the Excel file set to number versus general has any effect as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested to hear the solution to your problem. I had a similar issue when working with GIS coordinates. My workaround was to stop working with Excel formatted files. I used CSV's where I could clearly tell all of the digits were present before sending to my database.